# Magento 2.3.1- Problem with Payment not showing the payment options

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.3.1

[image: View of payment problem]

I am having issues with magneto. checkout page will only show place order without giving the option to proceed to entering credit card details. I did a test order and clicked the place order button. I received order confirmation emails and the order are visible at the back end.

how can i solve this issue?

I have already performed this commands:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/generation/* var/di pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento cache:flush
```